# bug in finding biggest element of a set

Tags: python

can someone explain to me why I have this result?

```
>>> a = set([(0, 1), (1, 0), (0, 0)])    
>>> b = set([(1, 2), (2, 0), (0, 2), (2, 1), (1, 1)])    
>>> max(a,b)    
set([(0, 1), (1, 0), (0, 0)])
>>> max(b,a)
set([(1, 2), (2, 0), (0, 2), (2, 1), (1, 1)])
```

Comment: If you want to find the biggest element of **one** set, then why would the code pass **both** sets to `max`? There are multiple possible questions here; it isn't clear what you wanted the code to do.

Answer (score 5):

For sets, `a < b` means `a` is a subset of `b`. Neither of your two sets is a subset of the other, so they're considered "equally large" and that's why you always just got the first argument.

Demo of set sorting:

```
>>> sorted([{5,6,7,8,9}, {1,2,3}, {1,2}, {1}, {1,2,3,4}])
[{8, 9, 5, 6, 7}, {1}, {1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3, 4}]
```

Here, `{5,6,7,8,9}` is neither a subset nor a superset of any of the others, so it's considered equally large and since it's at the beginning and the sort function is stable, it stays at its place. The other four however get sorted nicely, because `{1}` is a subset of `{1,2}`, etc.

However, since there's no total ordering among sets, sorting them is partially unpredictable. For example, here the `{5,6,7,8,9}` does get moved to another position:

```
>>> sorted([{1,2,3}, {1,2}, {5,6,7,8,9}, {1}, {1,2,3,4}])
[{1}, {1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}, {8, 9, 5, 6, 7}, {1, 2, 3, 4}]
```

If you want to sort sets another way, for example by size, then just use the appropriate `key`:

```
>>> sorted([{1,2,3}, {1,2}, {5,6,7,8,9}, {1}, {1,2,3,4}], key=len)
[{1}, {1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3, 4}, {8, 9, 5, 6, 7}]

>>> max([{1,2,3}, {1,2}, {5,6,7,8,9}, {1}, {1,2,3,4}], key=len)
{8, 9, 5, 6, 7}
```

Comment: do we have an explanation why this is the case? Why not sort the sets by their length?

Comment: @JeanDupont "<", or rather "⊂", is just the standard "comparison" of sets. If you want to say that a set has fewer elements, say "|A| < |B|". Or in Python, `len(A) < len(B)`. And it's equally trivial to sort sets by size, see the bottom of my updated answer.